# Accessing non-public tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, salesforce

I have used Heroku Connect to access salesforce data from my org. Here's how it's accessed normally via pure Ruby code. I'd like to know the equivalent in RoR

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'salesforce.contact'
end

get "/contacts" do
  @contacts = Contact.all
  erb :index
end
```

When I check the Postgres tables it shows the usual models in my app are under **public** and the ones imported by heroku are under **salesforce** schema. 
Q: How are non-public tables accessed in RoR? Do I create a new 'model'?

Comment: What do you mean by "pure Ruby code" `ActiveRecord::Base` is a Rails class.

Comment: @Arjan Ruby app without rails